# Delayed background task to run once after series of events

Tags: android, multithreading, background, android-handler, android-background

I implemented this with combination of `HandlerThread` inside a `Service`, using `removeCallbacks` of the `Handler` for the task and then re- `postDelayed` the task to assure it is only runs once and after the wanted delay has passed from the last event, all this while holding a `WakeLock` to make sure the device doesn't go to sleep before the task is due and completed its run.

This was a long time ago, and i would like to implement this while benefiting from the built in support of newer Android components to count for better battery usage being network type sensitive, run only while charging etc. I guess Android progressed since then and there might be a better option nowadays, for example, there might be a way the new [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) can come in handy.

Is there a better option to implement it using more recent android components and libraries to have a less boilerplate code and better performance readability and reliability than the way I implemented it before?

Answer (score 0):

Writing heavily multi-threaded Android apps can be quite difficult and overwhelming since there are lot of moving parts to take care of. This, along with many other reasons convinced us to make **significant use of RxJava** in our Android apps.

We all know (and secretly admit) how difficult multi-threading can get in Java. Executing a piece of code in a background thread and getting results back in the UI thread, might sound easy, but in reality, there are a lot of tricky situations to take care of.

**RxJava** makes it insanely easy to perform several complex operations in any thread of your choice, maintaining proper synchronization and letting you switch threads seamlessly.

Have a look here for more info:
  https://blog.gojekengineering.com/multi-threading-like-a-boss-in-android-with-rxjava-2-b8b7cf6eb5e2

Comment: I agree with you, im familiar with RXJava, although its just a tool to help implement just a minor feature of the complete requirements in the OQ